# Elasticsearch query only year with a custom date format

Tags: elasticsearch

Given I have a index mapping as following

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy||yyyy-MM"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this means I can put documents in all of the allowed date types 
if I make sure that all documents support the date format yyyy-MM-dd I would like to use the match query to allow me to search across different types such as providing documents that have the field date as follows
doc1 - date: 2016-1-1
doc2 - date: 2017-1-4
doc3 - date: 2016-2-1

I want to be able to use the match to provide a query with only 2016 and get back doc2 and doc3 back 
and I would also like to be able to search using 2016-1 currently elasticsearch does not care and throws no exception as it should use all date types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_format_in_range_queries) is what you're looking for.  I haven't used it myself, so I can't say for sure on the syntax, but something like the following should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range" : {
      "born" : {
        "gte": "2016",
        "lte": "2016",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd||yyyy||yyyy-MM"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Earlier versions used a range filter instead of a query, but if you're on 5.x or newer, you should be fine with the range query.